# Why can't a control unit detect this 12 volt signal while my multimeter can?

Tags: voltage-detector

I work as a contractor installing stop request signs on busses.  The stop request sign is basically a device that illuminates when a rider pulls the stop cord.  When it is pulled, 12v is sent to the incadescent bulb inside the sign, and it lights up.

The new sign we install is an LED display that gets its power from a separate source.  Most of the time, we would tap directly into the old stop sign wire to detect when the pull cord has been activated.  However, on some older busses, I have noticed that this doesn't work.  Although my multimeter shows 12 volts on the wire when the stop request has been activated, the control unit that the sign is hooked up to does not.  Therefore, the sign does not light.  I was instructed to wire the signal from the sign to a relay.  This way, the sign activates the relay, and the relay, using another 12 volt source (from battery) tells the control unit that the pull cord has been activated.  This solves the problem.

My question is, how does this work?  I don't have an electronics background, so I'm not sure how the control unit detects the signal. How come I can read 12 volts on this wire but the control unit can't detect this 12v, but can detect the 12v passing through the relay from the battery?

Thank you for your insight,  I really appreciate you guys taking the time to read this.

Comment: Do you know how the control unit is grounded?  My first thought would be that there is a floating ground that is being pulled up when the cord is activated.  If the 12V line and separate source (5V?) have different grounds, then the control unit's ground could be pulled around by the 12V signal.  Adding the relay might make you use each ground correctly on different sides of the relay.

Comment: I agree with Seth, it is probably to isolate the grounds.  For clarity: voltage is always with respect to something.  So you can measure 12V across two terminals.  The bottom terminal voltage could be 60V and the top terminal voltage 72V, you will still read 12V.  If you attach a '12V' signal to the top terminal it will not register as a 'high' value anymore (since the lower terminal is 60V compared to 12V).

Comment: The 12 v your multimeter reads probably sourced from high impedance source. Did you take the measurement while the line is loaded? Unloaded voltage usually higher and tend to drop if the source has high impedance.

Comment: Both the relay and the control unit use the same chassis ground tie in point on the bus bar.  The old sign is probably receiving it's power from a Plc because this wire is purple, and purple wires on this bus type, New Flyere, are suppose to be Plc outputs.  The way our new system works is that the control unit detects an active high of 12 volts on this wire, and then the new led sign will light when the control unit tells it to through its j1708 connection.   We are not actually powering the new led sign from the 12 volt line of the old sign.

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect that the LED sign is using a DC-DC converter internally and that there is no connection between the power in and the power out. I've represented this as a transformer isolation in Figure 1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgMaq5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. This circuit has no return path for the stop button current. The LED won't light.*

The result is that when you feed +12 V in to the new sign that the LED won't light as there is no current return path.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0SE4V.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. By adding a relay we can create a complete circuit for the STOP button and for the LED circuit.*

Adding the relay solves this problem but you must be connecting the LED to the sign's internal supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUfK5A.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Working without a relay.*

Connecting A-A *or* B-B (but not both) in Figure 3 would allow the circuit to work without a relay as there would be a reference between the two circuits. (You would need to reverse-engineer the LED sign to be sure. In particular, you would need to confirm that the LED sign is 12 V internally.) The downside is that the manufacturer could change the device design at some stage and you would risk damage on a future replacement.